Is there a way to keep doing normal attacks after clicking an enemy once in Grim Dawn?
Is there a way in Grim Dawn to where when I click/target an enemy, my character will keep attacking it normally until it dies while I do something else? I tried out Classic Targeting but I don't see a difference when I toggle it on or off.
A lot of MMOs have this option and I know Grim Dawn is not an MMO but I would still want to know if it's possible to do it.

So you're saying, not that you want to hold the button down and lock on to the enemy, but that you want to attack once, and have your character automatically keep attacking until you redirect your character?

Classic Targeting locks you to the enemy you're attacking (so even if you move the cursor off, you'll keep attacking), but you still have to hold down the mouse button.

Here's a program which appears to be free that lets you get this kind of control over the mouse.  I haven't tried it, but I think you could configure it to simulate holding the mouse button down: https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

@Kyralessa that's exactly what I wanted to do, click once and the character keeps attacking until the clicked enemy dies
